# HTML & JavaScript Traffic Light

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have to write a piece of code for a working traffic light, where the light changes upon button click and then another button that will launch automatic sequence that will change the lights itself after x time. Now as this is a research task for a CS, I was looking for simple codes to develop from, and found the following link from which I have created the following code;

https://jsfiddle.net/87pjbdyb/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Traffic Light</title>
<script>
var lightStates = {red:0,amber:1,green:2};
var currentState = lightStates.red;

document.getElementById('changeBtn').onclick=function(){
    changeState();
};


function changeState()
{
    clear();
  switch(currentState)
  {
    case lightStates.red:
    {
      document.getElementById("red").className ="light red";
      currentState =  lightStates.amber;
    }
    break;
    case lightStates.amber:
    {
      document.getElementById("amber").className ="light amber";
      currentState = lightStates.green;
    } break;
     case lightStates.green:
    {
      document.getElementById("green").className ="light green";
      currentState = lightStates.red;
    } break;
   }
}

function clear(){
   document.getElementById("red").className ="light off";
   document.getElementById("amber").className ="light off";
   document.getElementById("green").className ="light off";
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .traffic-light
{
  width:50px;
  height:75px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.light
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.red
{
  background-color:red
}
.amber
{
  background-color:yellow
}
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}

.off
{
  background-color:transparent;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="traffic-light">
  <div class="light off" id="red"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="amber"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="green"></div>
</div>
<button id="changeBtn">Change</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Now on the website provided, the traffic light seems to work perfectly while on mine the traffic light is shown but I seem not to be able to get any colours to be shown. Could anyone please point me in direction of where I am going wrong as I have minimal experience in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **setInterval** function of JavaScript and call it on a button click. and if the button is clicked again clear the interval.

Here `launchAuto()` is a function which will set up an interval of 1 second (1000ms) and call the changeState() function after every 1 second.

If the button is clicked again i.e `interval != ""` then it will clear the interval.

```js
var lightStates = {red:0,amber:1,green:2};
var currentState = lightStates.red;

interval = "";

function launchAuto()
{
  if(interval == "")
  {
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    changeState();
    }, 1000);
  }
  else
  {
      clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
document.getElementById('changeBtn').onclick=function(){
    changeState();
};


function changeState()
{
    clear();
  switch(currentState)
  {
    case lightStates.red:
    {
      document.getElementById("red").className ="light red";
      currentState =  lightStates.amber;
    }
    break;
    case lightStates.amber:
    {
      document.getElementById("amber").className ="light amber";
      currentState = lightStates.green;
    } break;
     case lightStates.green:
    {
      document.getElementById("green").className ="light green";
      currentState = lightStates.red;
    } break;
   }
}

function clear(){
   document.getElementById("red").className ="light off";
   document.getElementById("amber").className ="light off";
   document.getElementById("green").className ="light off";
}
```

```css
    .traffic-light
{
  width:50px;
  height:75px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.light
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.red
{
  background-color:red
}
.amber
{
  background-color:yellow
}
.green
{
  background-color:green;
}

.off
{
  background-color:transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="traffic-light">
  <div class="light off" id="red"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="amber"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="green"></div>
</div>
<button id="changeBtn">Change</button>
<button onClick="launchAuto();">Automatic</button>
```

Comment: Sorry must've explained it wrong but the problem I am having is that when the button is pressed, the red light is meant to be shown however nothing changes upon button click. However thanks for helping me in advance for the second part of the task.